# Why does the image values not change based on threshold

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am using an ndarray from numpy to represent a grey-scale image. I am trying to change some pixel values to either black or white depending on a threshold.  The first implementation is as follows:

```
    bwImage = image #ndArray
    for h in range(image.shape[0]):
        for w in range(image.shape[1]):
            if image[h][w] > threshold:
                bwImage[h][w] = 0
            else:
                bwImage[h][w] = 255
    cv2.imwrite('testImg.jpg', bwImage)
```

When I write the array to the testImg.jpg I see the original image.  I then iterated over the ndArray to check if the values were actually changed.

```
bwImage = image
for h in range(image.shape[0]):
    for w in range(image.shape[1]):
        if image[h][w] > threshold:
            bwImage[h][w] = 0
        else:
            bwImage[h][w] = 255
#why does this have to be here to convert it to BW?
for h in range(image.shape[0]):
    for w in range(image.shape[1]):
        print image[h][w]

cv2.imwrite('testImg.jpg', bwImage)
```

This then saves the image as black and white.  Why is that?

I also tried doing the following:

```
image[image <= threshold] = 255
image[image > threshold] = 0
cv2.imwrite('testImg.jpg', bwImage)
```

Depending on which statement is first determines if the save of the image is completely black or white.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1

I tried your first snippet of code without the print statements and it works just fine (using cv2 version 3.0.0, numpy 1.9.2).  Two things to note however are that

1. `bwImage = image` does not copy the image, it just creates another pointer to image -> all modifications to `bwImage` are done in-place to the initial `image`
2. The resulting image is "inverted" from original grayscale image since you assign high values (white) when below threshold (dark) and vice-versa

### Method 2

The issue here is that because you are doing an inverted thresholding in-place, your first assignment sets all values *less than* the threshold to 255 in-place. Then your second assignment assigns all values more than the threshold (which now includes everything) to black.

If you want to do a non-inverted threshold, that can be accomplished simply by switching the operators:

```
image[image > threshold] = 255
image[image <= threshold] = 0
```

If you want to do the inverted thresholding as in **method 1**, you'll have to copy the image and then you can use the original image as a mask without destroying the original pixel info:

```
image_copy = image.copy()
image_copy[image <= threshold] = 255
image_copy[image > threshold] = 0
cv2.imshow('image',image_copy)
```